# Scout SDK 2.5: Map cache, control and provide offline search?

Tags: android, skmaps

Just updated to 2.5 and start digging with map cache options.
When I start the app without pre-cached maps with Online connectivity mode I see that the app is able to download some map pieces in order to show my location and what is around me, which is great. Once I have this downloaded by SDK, I can go offline and use the downloaded piece again. This leads to few questions:

1. What amount of data is downloaded in order to show information about current location and nearby? Can we control this amount?
2. Where the data is stored? Can we change the location for downloaded information?
3. How we can use downloaded data for offline address search and reverse geocoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of downloaded information is usually restricted to the visited areas & depends on the zoom level used - the vector tiles are split both on a vertical level (limited by bounding box) and on a horizontal level (i.e. highways are held in a separate layer than primary roads) making it possible to always have something visible on the map - even when zooming out you will see the major roads (even in areas you have not visited before) and only when zooming in additional map features will be loaded.

This information will be stored in the cache - you can configure the size of the cache via the [SKTilesCacheManager](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.0/com/skobbler/ngx/cache/SKTilesCacheManager.html) class (by default we provide a value that we deem optimal for the phones specific software/hardware config but you can override this) - the location is not configurable for the cache - what you can configure is the offline maps storage location - see the [dedicated documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec022) chapter about multiple storages.

For geocoding & reverse geocoding you will need to have the map & index files available as offline maps (both are downloaded when getting & installing an offline map) - once this is done search for addresses, POIs and perform reverse geocodes in the downloaded maps - see the documentation chapters about this ([here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec019), [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec020) and [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec021))